# HeadlessException when trying to launch/run jProfiler 9 on Fedora 24 Workstation?

Tags: fedora, jprofiler

I just installed a fresh copy of Fedora 24 Workstation and did a full `dnf update` on the entire system.

Then I installed the jProfiler rpm from the jProfiler site.

However, when I try to launch jProfiler (either from the /opt/jprofiler9/jProfiler.desktop icon or from /opt/jprofiler9/bin/jprofiler shell script), I get the following error message:

```
java.awt.HeadlessException
  at java.awt.SplashScreen.getSplashScreen(SplashScreen.java:117)
  at com.exe4j.runtime.splash.AwtSplashScreen.<init>(AwtSplashScreen.java:17)
  at com.exe4j.runtime.splash.SplashEngine.setJavaSplashScreenConfig(SplashEngine.java:17)
  at com.install4j.runtime.launcher.UnixLauncher.main(UnixLauncher.java:50)
```

I've tried setting my display using `DISPLAY=0.0` or even `DISPLAY=:0`, but neither seem to make any difference/impact.

Any suggestions how to get this to work?  I suspect it is something obvious that I am overlooking.

Answer (score 1):

After a bunch of trial and error, I finally tried to install the Oracle Hotspot JRE instead of the OpenJDK JRE.  I downloaded Oracle's JDK, installed it, and then configured it as the system default using:

```
sudo alternatives --config java
```

Now everything works properly with Oracle JRE.

Comment: I suspect you may have only have had the headless JRE package installed. That package is not able to run GUI applications.